# Tkinter entry validation: Check for a valid color or portion of a color

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Recently, I have found that the validation option of Entry widgets is very useful (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content)). I recently tried to write a validation command that would verify that the user was typing a hex code, or a named color. I wrote this, and it works great for hex codes, and it sporadically works for colors. It runs on every keypress, among other things. (`validate=ALL`)

```
def checkColorValid(P):
    global backgroundColor
    if not P:
        return True

    if P.lower() in colors:
        backgroundColor = P
        return True

    if P[0] == '#':
        try:
            if len(P) == 1:
                return True
            int(P[1:], 16)
            if len(P) < 8:
                backgroundColor = P
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except ValueError:
            return False

    for color in colors:
        if color.startswith(P.lower()):
            return True
```

`colors` is a list of all valid named colors.
The validation code works, unless you are trying to type a named color, and start typing the same character over and over again. Once that happens, the validation appears to simply stop working. It no longer runs at all, until you restart the program.

Comment: You described what your program is doing, but you didn't actually ask a question. What is it you need help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible for the validation code to return `None` rather than `True` or `False`. Perhaps adding a final return statement will help.

Comment: That is the issue. When the validation command returns None, it appears to hang and stop running forever. Adding a `return False` to the bottom of the method makes it work in all cases.

Comment: @BryanOakley, On an unrelated topic, is there a way in `tk` to check if a certain color name is valid to be used in `tk` (or `ttk`) widgets. To explain, `bg='sky blue'` will work as we know but `bg='skyblue'` wouldn't. How do we check if it's a valid color name or not (of course the only other approach I can think of is to make a list of all the `tk` colors and check for inclusion).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found this page in a search.  Did not like it; but could not think of anything better.  Then realized I was over-thinking it.  Python has a great way to test anything for valid or not, 'try'.  Does not have to be bg; just whatever object is easy to use in whatever you a testing colors for.

```py
def ColorTest(SomeColor):
    IsGood = True
    ColorTest=Toplevel()
    try:
        ColorTest['bg'] = SomeColor # Set backround color
        #print(SomeColor+' is a valid color')
        ColorTest.destroy()
        return IsGood
        
    except:
        #print(SomeColor+' is an invalid color')
        IsGood = False
        ColorTest.destroy()
        return IsGood
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32387362)